# How to make a UI that fits all screens and widths

Tags: windows-phone-8

Being new to Windows Mobile Development, (not a universal application)

I am making a GUI login page where there are a few `TextBlock`and `TextBox`.

How can I position UI elements to fit all screens,

For example, for those who are familiar with Adobe Flash, you can position the anchor point of an object in the middle, and then use

```
this.x = Stage.stageWithX/2;
```

this ensures that no matter what the screens with is, the objects x position will be positioned in the middle.

How is this achieved in Windows Mobile, so when tested on different devices I would get similar look and feel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad to answer yet I will try to get you started with windows phone xaml design.

The xaml elements have properties named [HorizontalAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment) and [VerticalAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.verticalalignment). If you set the values of the property to stretch the element occupies the available total space.

In your scenario, have a grid with two columns and set the alignment properties of the element. The xaml code:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <TextBlock Text="Hello"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
     <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="World"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Great example, I just need to access those properties and set the values.